# edit ASCII value of a character in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ascii

I am trying to update the ASCII value of each character of a string array in bash on which I want to add 2 to the existing character ASCII value.

Example:

```
declare -a x =("j" "a" "f" "a" "r")
```

I want to update the ASCII value incrementing the existing by 2 , such "j" will become "l"

I can't find anything dealing with the ASCII value beyond 
`print f '%d' "'$char"`

Can anyone help me please?

And also when I try to copy an array into another it doesn't work 
note that I am using

```
declare -a temp=("${x[@]}")
```

What is wrong with it?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn an integer into a char by first using printf to turn it into an octal escape sequence (like `\123`) and then using that a printf format string to produce the character:

```
#!/bin/bash
char="j"
printf -v num %d "'$char"
(( num += 2 ))
printf -v newchar \\$(printf '%03o' "$num")
echo "$newchar"
```

This only works for ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

It seems `tr` can help you here:

```
y=($(echo ${x[@]} | tr a-z c-zab))
```

`tr` maps characters from one set to another. In this example, from the set of `a b c ... z`, it maps to `c d e ... z a b`. So, you're effectively "rotating" the characters. This principle is used by the [ROT13 cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13).

Comment: actually i've supposed the value is 2 , what if the value is dynamic !! btw i want to implement Vigenere cipher if this would help you understand my point !!

Comment: In that case, I don't think `bash` is the right tool here. Why do you want to use `bash`?

Comment: cause my final project must be implemented using bash :/